# For what value of $(a+b)$ will all roots of $f(x)=x^4-8x^3+ax^2+bx+16$ be positive?

Tags: polynomials, roots, quartics

I was thinking of using [Descartes' rule of signs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DescartesSignRule.html), from which I find there are at most 2 positive roots and 2 negative roots of the given equation.

Also, $f(\infty)>0$ and $f(0)>0$ imply that either there are no real roots or 2 real roots in $(0,\infty)$. Similar is the case for $(-\infty,0)$.

If I could factor $f'(x)=4x^3-24x^2+2ax+b$ and find its roots, then the real and distinct roots of $f(x)$ will be separated by those of $f'(x)$. How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Hint: start by studying $f''$.

Comment: I don't understand the rule of signs conclusion.  $a$ and $b$ can be positive or negative, and if $a > 0$ and $b < 0$, then DRoS says $f(x)$ has 0, 2, or 4 positive roots.  And actually it would have to be 4 because there'd be 0 negative roots.

Comment: @tilper Yes you are correct. I hadn't gone that far with my conclusion.

Comment: @Dark Could you elaborate? What can I conclude from $6x(x-4)=-a$ for $f''=0$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom you should be able to derive the variations of $f''$ and where it takes its extreme values. From there you can deduce the same for $f'$. Finally, you can deduce the same for $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider first the case when $b=-32$.

$$f_1(x)=x^4-8x^3+ax^2-32x+16=0\iff a=\frac{-x^4+8x^3+32x-16}{x^2}$$
Now, let
$$g(x):=\frac{-x^4+8x^3+32x-16}{x^2}$$
Then,
$$g'(x)=\frac{-2 (x-2)^3 (x+2)}{x^3}$$

So, $g(x)$ is increasing for $x\lt -2$ or $0\lt x\lt 2$, and is decreasing for $-2\lt x\lt 0$ or $x\gt 2$ with $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}g(x)=-\infty,\lim_{x\to 0^{\pm}}g(x)=-\infty$.

Now considering the graph of $y=g(x)$ gives that
$$\begin{align}&\text{all roots of $f_1(x)$ are positive}\\&\implies \text{all $x$ coordinates of the intersection points of $y=a$ with $y=g(x)$ are positive}\\&\implies a=24\ (=g(2))\\&\implies a+b=-8\end{align}$$

By the way, for $a=28, b=-36$ where $a+b=-8$, 
$$f_2(x)=x^4-8x^3+28x^2-36x+16$$
$$f'_2(x)=4x^3-24x^2+56x-36=4(x-1)\left(\left(x-\frac 52\right)^2+\frac{11}{4}\right)$$
so $f_2(x)$ is decreasing for $x\lt 1$ and is increasing for $x\gt 1$ with $f_2(1)=1\gt 0$ from which $f_2(x)\gt 0$ follows. Hence, $f_2(x)$ has no real roots.

Therefore, there are no $a+b$ such that all roots of $f(x)$ are positive.

Comment: So the final answer should be $a+b=-8$? Do you give a counterexample in the end? And, why do you take $b=-32$ in the first place?

Comment: @StubbornAtom: First of all, my understanding is that the title says that given $a+b=k$ where $k$ is a *constant*, for what value of $a+b$ will all roots of $f(x)$ be positive **for every pair of $(a,b)$ such that $a+b=k$**? So (1) the final answer is not $a+b=-8$ because there are no real roots for $a=28, b=-36$ where $a+b=-8$. (2) Considering the case where $b=-32$, we have to have $a=24\implies a+b=-8$, but $a+b=-8$ is not sufficient as I wrote. (3) Because I have realized that the all roots of $f(x)=(x-2)^2$ are positive. Anyway, what you want to ask might not be the same as the title...

Answer (score 2):

**Corrected version:**
The roots are nonegative only for $a=24$ and $b=-32$, i.e. $a+b=-8$.

Proof.
Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ denote the roots. Then by Vieta's formula
$$
x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 8,\ \text{ and } x_1x_2x_3x_4 = 16.
$$
If the roots are positive, then
$$
8 = x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 \geq 4(x_1x_2x_3x_4)^{1/4}=8,
$$
implying $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=2$. Since $f(x) = (x-2)^4=x^4-8x^3+24x^2-32x+16$, it follows that $a=24$ and $b=-32$, i.e. $a+b=-8$.

**The previous version (contains a typo in the last line):**

It seems that $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ cannot be all nonnegative for any values of $a$ and $b$.

Proof.
Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ denote the roots. Then by Vieta's formula
$$
x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 8,\ \text{ and } x_1x_2x_3x_4 = 16.
$$
If the roots are positive, then
$$
8 = x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 \geq 4(x_1x_2x_3x_4)^{1/4}=8,
$$
implying $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=2$. Thus, $f(x) = (x-2)^4=x^4-4x^3+\dots\ne x^4-8x^3+\dots$, a contradiction.

Comment: $(x-2)^4=x^4\color{red}{-8}x^3+24x^2-32x+16$.

Comment: @mathlove: Yes, sure, I have corrected the answer.