# Equation of fourth degree

Tags: linear-algebra

How to advance with this question??

The equation $x^4 - 4x^3 + ax^2 +bx+1 $ has four positive roots.$ (a-b)$ is equal to?

I have tried reciprocal equations , rational roots theorem and factorization but couldn't solve.

Comment: is $a-b$ an expression or a particular constant ?

Comment: Similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1866624/321264.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=4$ and $x_1x_2x_3x_4=1$ imply (why?) that $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=1$, where $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ are the four positive roots.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ be those four roots. then $\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta = 4$ and $\alpha \beta \gamma \delta=1$. Now one can use the equality case of the [AM-GM Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)